# mvc3 View checking a boolean c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering how I could do this Boolean check. I'm not very good with mvc3 Views...

Error   1   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

```
@model Project.Domain.Worker //active is a value in worker  
@if (model => model.active == true) {  //this doesn't work 
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.param)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.param)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.param)
        </div>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `model.active` is a boolean, you can simply do:

```
@if (Model.active)
```

When dealing with boolean types, you never need to compare them to `true` or `false`.

Your confusion may arise from HTML helpers taking a lambda - an `if` cannot take a lambda.

Comment: @DavidVdd - And when accessing the model using `Model` (capital M)?